# Filtering pytest tests by class name

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python script containing multiple classes that group test cases for pytest.
Example:

```
class TestA:
    def test_a(self):
        pass

class TestB:
    def test_b(self):
        pass
```

I would like to filter tests to be executed with -k parameter by providing class name.
Pytest references test cases like this:

```
pytest_wild.py::TestA::test_a
```

so I thought I can call pytest like this:

```
pytest mytests.py -k "pytest_wild.py::TestA"
```

but unfortunately it doesn't catch test from TestA class.
Any ideas ?

Alternatively I can split them to separate scripts or use marks - but the simplest would be to filter by class name.

Comment: Use just `-k TestA`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've just figured it out :) Sometimes asking a question itself helps to find a solution :)

Comment: Some test tools allow you to specify a path through directory / module to test class to test method so you can run one or a limited group of associated tests. I thought `pytest` did this but I can't see that in the options now. Only the `-k` pattern match. So it has to be by pattern match, and not a verified path you can walk down to the test(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer for myself. Providing only class name to -k param works well.

```
pytest mytests.py -k "TestA"
```

Comment: How to filter some test cases in class class01, and some other test cases in class class02 ?